# Does OpenTok provide HIPAA compliant video recording?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am building a patient-therapist video conference app which needs the meeting recording should be stored only on my server, not on any third party servers like TokBox cloud storage.

The author in this article https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204951424-How-can-I-use-archiving-as-part-of-a-HIPAA-compliant-application- says we can turn off the cloud storage fallback.

Does OpenTok upload the meeting recording in my Amazon S3 storage after the meeting is stopped or initiates the recording upload when the meeting is in progress?

In the above article, the author says, immediately after attempting the upload, the file is deleted from the server where it was recorded.

Does this mean, OpenTok save meeting recording even if the cloud storage is turned off?

Can I claim my website supports HIPAA compliant video conference meeting and video recording if I integrate OpenTok in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTok QA Engineer here.

Your recording is uploaded to your storage right after the archive is stopped. The live session can still continue, but the rest of it will not be recorded, then. After the file has been successfully uploaded, it is completely removed from our servers. Should any error happen, we will retry uploading it for up to 24 hours, after which, we won't retry anymore. 72 hours after the archive was started, the files will be wiped out from the servers, no matter if they have been successfully uploaded or not.

If the OpenTok fallback storage is turned off, the archive will be recorded, and only be in our servers the minimum required time to generate the MP4 file, and upload it.

Yes, you can claim it, as long as you disable the OpenTok fallback.